# Replace set of multiple occurring elements in Numpy array with corresponding values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Please consider the following code:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 6])
mapping = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 55, 66, 70, 80, 90])
res = np.zeros_like(arr)
min_val = 0
max_val = 10

for val in range(min_val, max_val):
    res[arr == val] = mapping[val]

print(res)
```

The Numpy array `arr` can have multiple occurrences of integers from interval `[min_val, max_val)`. `mapping` array will have mappings for each integer and the size of the `mapping` array will be `max_val`. `res` array is the resultant array.

The `for` loop replaces multiple occurring elements in `arr` with the corresponding value in the `mapping`. For example, `0` value in the `arr` will be replaced with `mapping[0]` and `5` in `arr` with `mapping[5]`.

The result of the above code is as below.

`[ 0 10 30 55 55 66 70 90 80 90 30 20 40 66]`

**Question**: How to do this operation using Numpy instead of `for` loop?

**Answer** is to use Numpy's [fancy indexing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html)

Comment: So, `mapping[arr]`?

Comment: exactly that is doing the job

Comment: @Divakar Absolutely, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `arr` as an indexing array for `mapping`:

```py
mapping[arr]
```

the output is

```
[ 0 10 30 55 55 66 70 90 80 90 30 20 40 66]
```

---

You can read on the official SciPy documentation about the [indexing arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).
Example from the documentation:

```py
>>> x = np.arange(10,1,-1)
>>> x
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2])
>>> x[np.array([3, 3, 1, 8])]
array([7, 7, 9, 2])
```

The values of the indexing array are used as an index for the source array.

This is also possible with [multidimensional arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```py
>>> x = array([[ 0,  1,  2],
...            [ 3,  4,  5],
...            [ 6,  7,  8],
...            [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> rows = np.array([[0, 0],
...                  [3, 3]], dtype=np.intp)
>>> columns = np.array([[0, 2],
...                     [0, 2]], dtype=np.intp)
>>> x[rows, columns]
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Albo, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `mapping[arr]` to access the correct element in the new Numpy array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 6])
>>> mapping = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 55, 66, 70, 80, 90])
>>> print(mapping[arr])
array([ 0, 10, 30, 55, 55, 66, 70, 90, 80, 90, 30, 20, 40, 66])
```

If you want it as a `list`:

```
>>> print(list(mapping[arr]))
[0, 10, 30, 55, 55, 66, 70, 90, 80, 90, 30, 20, 40, 66]
```